# how to create image slideshow in android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-imageview, android-handler

i am calling this medthod show() in onCreate()
, whats wrong in my code

```
 public void show()
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    int arr[]={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4};
                    int i=1;
                    do
                    {
                        i++;
                        try
                        {
                            imageView.setImageResource(arr[i]);
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                    }
                    while(i==arr.length);
                }
            },2000);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

i think it should wait for 2 sec. every time and show next image but its doing nothing even no error
i used toast to counter processing then i found its only reaching to first toast

Comment: Are you starting the inner Runnable?

Comment: no, i am starting outer runnable